# How to close a Terminal window while executing a file with node.js without stopping the process?

Tags: macos, node.js, terminal

When I execute a file with node.js (by typing "node example.js", maybe a http server), then, when I close the Terminal window (Mac OS X Lion), the process is stopped and doesn't answers on requests anymore. The same happens if I type "ctrl c" or "ctrl z". How can I close the Terminal without stopping the process, so my server continues answering on requests.

Comment: add `&` ie `node example.js &`

Comment: @JonathanOng: That's not sufficient.

Comment: I believe this is what the `nohup` utility is for. Try running your process using that.

Comment: @JonathanOng Even with the `&`, the parent process is still the terminal you're in and the process remains attached to the tty. When you kill the terminal, the process dies. The nohup command is correct. It actually detaches from the process (so its ppid = 1).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a combination of the `nohup` prefix command (to keep the process from being killed when the terminal closes) and the `&` suffix (to run the process in the background so it doesn't tie up the terminal):
`nohup node example.js &`

You should also look into [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) or similar tools that will also automatically restart the server if it crashes, and [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) which will automatically restart it when you change the code.